# Linux starting bash issue : command substitution issue

Tags: linux, bash, command-substitution

I try to start a new shell in my environment, but `bash` command has an issue:

```
$ bash
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
'ash: command substitution: line 1: `print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "'
```

Then I'm unable to escape with

```
$ ")^C
bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
'ash: command substitution: line 2: `print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "'
```

and must leave the shell with  - I guess this means it really opened a subshell.

The shell it opened has weird behavior , because for each command I type, it will repeat the four lines of above error.

I looked in `~/.bashrc` but the only thing it does is `umask 0022`.

`-x` doesn't give me much about my issue

```
$ bash -x
+ umask 0022
++ tput bold
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
... same error
```

Could this be linked to the `'` there is in `/ect/bashrc` in the comment line there:

```
if ! shopt -q login_shell ; then # We're not a login shell
   # Need to redefine pathmunge, it get's undefined at the end of /etc/profile
   pathmunge () {
     case ":${PATH}:" in
        *:"$1":*)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
                PATH=$PATH:$1
            else
                PATH=$1:$PATH
            fi
     esac
   }
```

Where should I look from here? Should I ask for `/etc/bashrc` to be fixed / modified in any way?

### edit

As suggested by someone, could this come from my `~/.profile`?

```
export PS1='$(tput bold)$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")'
trap 1 2 3

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export HTTPD_HOME=/pvar/product/httpd

        export EDITOR=/bin/vi
        export FCEDIT=/bin/vi
        export VISUAL=/bin/vi
        export HISTSIZE=5000
        export TMOUT=0
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: as a first observation, in the error i see : `if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; ` which is not correct, the `;` should be after the `]]` and after then there should be no `;`. same for the ` else; print`, no `;` needed

Comment: It works once I fixed this `.profile` issue. Thanks!

Comment: as a first observation, in the error i see : `if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; ` which is not correct, the `;` should be after the `]]` and after the `then` there should be no `;`. same for the `else; print`  - no `;` needed after the `else`

Answer (score 1):

I had to change my `.profile` to fix the line which builds the prompt (`PS1`):

```
export PS1='$(tput bold)$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")'
```

became

```
export PS1='$(tput bold)$(echo "`logname`@`hostname`:$(tput sgr0)" ; \
  if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]]; \
  then echo "~${PWD#$HOME}"; \
  else echo "${PWD}"; fi; echo "$ ")'
```

Now I'd like to find a way to avoid `echo` to skip a line (I had to replace `print` by `echo` because bash doesn't handle `print` by default).

Comment: bash handles `printf`

Comment: `echo -n` will not print newline character at the end of the output